# convert coordinates from non-orthogonal axes to cartesian in 3-dimensions

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I'm having issues converting from a non-orthogonal coordinate space (abc) to a cartesian space (xyz).

I think I may have just thought myself into a corner, and I can't get out.

The systems have a common origin. $\mathbf{a}$ is parallel to $\mathbf{x}$. The $ab$ plane is in the $xy$ plane. The angle between $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ is $\gamma$, $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ is $\alpha$, and $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ is $\beta$. All angles are less than $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and greater than $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

So far, I've figured out that my transformation matrix is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \cos\gamma & ?\\ 
0 & \sin\gamma & ?\\ 
0 & 0 & \sin\alpha\sin\beta
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Any light you can shed? Everything else that I've seen has been limited to 2D.

Edit: Now I'm not too sure on the last entry in that matrix...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we need to find the coordinates of the unit vectors of $abc$ space in terms of $xyz$ space. You have found the first two. Let the $xyz$ coordinates of the unit vector in $c$ direction be $(x,y,z)$. It satisfies:

$$(1,0,0)\cdot(x,y,z)=\cos{\beta}\\
(\cos{\gamma},\sin{\gamma},0)\cdot(x,y,z)=\cos{\alpha}\\
x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$

where I used the fact that $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=||\vec{u}|| ||\vec{v}||\cos{\theta}$. They can be easily solved. The $(x,y,z)$ will make the 3rd column.

Comment: Thanks. Now I just need to do a little simplification, but $x=\cos\beta$, $y=\frac{\cos\alpha-\cos\beta\cos\gamma}{\sin\gamma}$, and $z$ can be found from them as you said above.

Comment: @masher: That is correct.